# how to create new scope for each record of list of records which are repeating through while in java/jsp

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, jsp, while-loop

I get stuck with this problem, can someone let me out of it.

I am getting data (MongoDB) from servlet to jsp (MongoDB). I have list of (using `DBCursor`) documents which I have to show them, providing an edit and delete button to that. When I click on particular edit or delete, that particular record get modified.I am using ajax to post (edit/delete) data.
Provide individual scope for each record. Just like angular `ng-repeat`.

```
<% try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject tobj = cursor.next();
        dbObj = tobj;
        String id = (String) tobj.get("_id").toString();
        String firstName = (String) tobj.get("firstname");
        String lastName = (String) tobj.get("lastname");
        String emailId = (String) tobj.get("emailid");
%>

<tbody>
<form name= "" action="" method="POST">
<tr>
    <td><% out.println(firstName);%> </td>
    <td><% out.println(lastName);%> </td>
    <td><% out.println(emailId);%> </td>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= id%>">
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<%= firstName%>">
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<%= lastName%>">
<input type="hidden" name="emailid" value="<%= emailId%>">

<td>
    <button type="submit" name="Edit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw"></i>
        Edit
        <%  //out.print(dbObj);%>
    </button>
</td>
<td>
    <button type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i>
        Delete
        <%  //out.print(dbObj);%>
    </button>
</td>  
</tr>
</form>


<%
    }
    // out.print(dbObj);
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
%>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer long ago.
I have used "id" as reference to each element.
I've added onclick-javascript method passing "id" as argument. By this I've got solution.

Sorry, for late update.